# R cache is cleared when R studio breaks down

Tags: r, caching, rstudio

I wrote a program which is very time-consuming in importing data, so I use R.Cache to cache the function to obtain data. However, I found that each time my RStudio collapsed , the cache file was cleared and I had to import the data again. I am writing something in shiny, which is not stable and always incurs the breakdown problem.

Is there any good way to fix the problem?

Comment: We would need to be able to reproduce the problem to diagnose or solve it. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Does this happen with base R?